# Liferay: war getting copied at deployment, disappearing, but no app

Tags: liferay

I am working through the example in the Liferay documentation; I have created and built the little greeting applet and gotten no errors at compile or build.  I don't get any errors at deployment, either, but the application is showing up.

The deployment says it is copying my war file to portal-dir/deploy.  I have determined that I can copy the war file there, though something (I guess in the server) removes it after a few seconds.  But when I go to look at it in a browser off my local server, it is not there.

Does anyone know what I should look at to fix this?

Comment: Removal of war from deploy folder is normal behaviour. Are you saying you are not able to see your component in webapps folder?

Comment: My aoplogies to everyone; I meant to say/type that "my application is NOT showing up.", not that it was.  I found the error -- after thinking to look in the server log, which indicated there was a supporting portlet this portlet needed that was not installed.  I had removed it from the distribution because part of the documentation told me to remove "everything but X and Y" where X wasn't there, so I wasn't sure what they meant.  Thanks to all who looked at it.

Answer (score 1):

No need to fix anything here -this is how autodeployment works. Web archives found in deploy directory are removed from there, extracted, processed by Liferay and in the end you should be able to find them in ${catalina.home}\webapps (assuming that you're using a Tomcat bundle).